# How can I call custom javascript function globally in Nuxt js

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to use this javascript function to call on every template / layout / page in Nuxt.js (vuejs)

```
function setBoolean(val) {
  if (val) {
    return 1
  }
  return 0
}
```

on template I want to call it like

```
methods: {
  getValue() {
    this.value = setBoolean(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: You should then use `middleware` on the default layout of Nuxt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create a plugin and inject to project.

Look at the documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins

or

you can use [Vue filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html).

Comment: This could be better as a comment rather an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global `middleware` for your Nuxt project.

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  router: {
    middleware: ['custom-function']
  }
}
```

Then, write your function in `/middleware/custom-function.js` (at the root of your project). Like this, it will run globally.

More details available here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware/

Comment: I understand your idea but middleware functions run before rendering either a page or a group of pages (layout). Can you help me with this?

Comment: Not sure to get the issue here, isn't it what you want ?